# Trigger and Count(*) not working

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote trigger to check the if the customer had any suspended account. If yes, he will not be able to create a new account however when I try to do a insert, the insert still go through. Can some help me with this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SuspendedAccount
BEFORE INSERT ON ACCOUNT

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

varIsProblemAccount Int;

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO varIsProblemAccount
FROM ACCOUNT
WHERE CUSTID = :new.custID
    AND ACCSTATUS = 'Suspended';

IF (varIsProblemAccount >= 1) THEN      
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*************************************************');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('   Transaction canceled. ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('   Refer customer to the manager immediately. ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('**************************************************');
        RETURN;
    END;

ELSIF (varIsProblemAccount = 0) THEN

    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*************************************************');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('   Transaction completed. ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('   Thank the customer for their business. ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('**************************************************');
    END;
END IF;
END;
```

Sorry, i tried to change to 0 since it can never be "NULL" but its still do not work

Comment: I thought that you could not do DML in a trigger on the same table the trigger is on. That this would raise a "mutating table" exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger doesn't do anything to prevent the INSERT - RETURN just prematurely exits the trigger body.

If you want to prevent the INSERT, you should raise an exception instead:

```
IF (varIsProblemAccount >= 1) THEN      
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Existing account found');
END;
```

Comment: Also, DBMS_OUTPUT in triggers and stored procedures cannot print and will not print anything to a terminal.  It works for debugging from sqlplus, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your else-condition!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SuspendedAccount
BEFORE INSERT ON ACCOUNT

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

varIsProblemAccount Int;

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO varIsProblemAccount
FROM ACCOUNT
WHERE CUSTID = :new.custID
    AND ACCSTATUS = 'Suspended';

IF (varIsProblemAccount >= 1) THEN      
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*************************************************');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('   Transaction canceled. ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('   Refer customer to the manager immediately. ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('**************************************************');
        RETURN;
    END;

-- count() never returns NULL
ELSIF (varIsProblemAccount = 0) THEN

    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('*************************************************');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('   Transaction completed. ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('   Thank the customer for their business. ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('**************************************************');
    END;
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following code

```
ELSIF (varIsProblemAccount = null) THEN
```

to

```
ELSIF (varIsProblemAccount = 0) THEN
```

Comment: or of course, simply `else`, as it would be zero if it didn't go into the initial IF.